# Combine all polymer files (micro, mini) into a single file?

Tags: gulp, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to combine `polymer.html`, `polymer-mini.html` and `polymer-micro.html` into a single file using gulp or some means?

Comment: still have a problem?? if you got an answer please close this question.

Comment: Still haven't gotten around to it. Probably this weekend. Once I do, I will certainly close the question - sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vulcanize this is the official tool

https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize

install:

```
npm install -g vulcanize
```

use:

```
vulcanize target.html > build.html
```

you have also gulp-vulcanize.. that uses this tool.

it combine all  the imports into one single file. it gives you some more options like remove docs and more.

if you want to combine only this 3 files you can create one html that import the 3 files and vulcanize this file.

Answer (score 0):

Another tool that helps doing that is [Polybuild](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polybuild) (which utilizes Vulcanize)

> An all-in-one build tool for Polymer apps
>   Polybuild combines vulcanize, crisper, and polyclean into one easy to use solution for optimizing Polymer applications for production.

Install

```
npm install -g polybuild
```

Use

```
polybuild index.html
```